# What does CF2 mean when buying a laptop?

Tags: laptop

I'm currently looking at a high spec laptop which is about half price, it seems dodgy and I realised all the laptops have different "CF" values in their title...

for example gigabyte P15F R5-CF2

P15F R5 being the model number, and then there's just a mysterious CF2

I'm worried because some sites show that exact model with a different CF value, and the price is dramatically different... thanks to whoever can shed some light! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF2 in this context denotes the configuration of hardware components of the P15F R5 platform.

There may be several P15F R5 models, and CF2 is used by the OEM to tell them apart / what is in that configuration.

This is why you may see a computer with almost identical specs being priced a little higher or lower, depending on the hardware configuration.

Comment: thats a lot easier than some of the way's Dell or HP handle exact hardware configurations within a SKU or a Line. They generally don't publish them at all, and then make you go to a support page that describes how to check the last 4 chars of the model number to identify the real model.

Comment: Like Frank Thomas has stated, it is basically the ACTUAL model number / model code.

Comment: So how would I go about finding what the spec changes were? It's not that exact model but it's similar, and there's nothing on the gigabyte website. Will it be EXTREMELY different? It's a CF2 model if that helps

Comment: So, the CF2 suffix provides the OEM / customer with a baseline description of what is in the computer. **ALL HYPOTHETICAL** It is possible that they may offer the baseline CF2 machine with an i5, gtx960m and 8gb ddr3. So if you wanted something else, like an i7 or maybe 16gb ddr3, you could customize it to fit that specification but ultimately it started as a baseline CF2 machine, which the OEM would be able to refer to.

Comment: If you wanted to see what the specification changes are - just use comparative analysis and you will see that there may be incremental differences between the two units.

Comment: I looked at the Gigabyte website looking for more information, and like you, found none. So it is most likely that there are several P15F R5 laptops, but the different 'suffixes' like CF2 are what differentiate it from other machines whether they are being shipped to a retailer or to a private party. I hope I clarified that for you.

Comment: Really grateful man! I'm going to buy a cf2 version and hope there are no hardware changes :D